# Problema al traducir etiquetas Filter by price y Filter by Categories de WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy desarrollando una tienda con WooCommerce me aparece la página de la tienda traducida pero las etiquetas de Filter by price y Filter by Categories no.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías usar Loco Translate para eso o un Snippet propio.

Comment: Intenté agregar un código en el function.php del tema pero no me funciona.

Comment: Ahora le paso mi Snippet

Answer (score 0):

Bien, como le dije en el comentario. Lo más "fácil" (aunque no optimo) es usar **Loco Translate** para traducir textos o párrafos en WP.

Yo he creado un Plugin propio con todos mis Snippets y uno de ellos hace justo eso, me traduce palabras y frases.

```php
/* Spanish Bill Labels */
add_filter( 'gettext', 'dcms_change_traduction_text', 10, 3 );
function dcms_change_traduction_text( $translated, $original, $domain ) {
    if ( $translated == "No products were found matching your selection" ) {
        $translated = "POR EL MOMENTO ESTAMOS TRABAJANDO EN ESTA SECCIÓN.
        PRONTO PODRÁS DISFRUTAR DE TODAS LAS OFERTAS DE ESTA CATEGORÍA EN NUESTRA WEB. 
        AGRADECEMOS TU PACIENCIA. Y TE RECORDAMOS QUE ESTOS PRODUCTOS ESTAN 
        DISPONIBLES EN NUESTRA TIENDA FISICA. PARA INFORMACIÓN SOBRE PRECIOS
        Y STOCK DE ESTOS PRODUCTOS LLAMA AL O VISITANOS EN...";
    }
    switch ($translated) {
        case $translated == "Product":
            $translated = "Producto";
            break;
        case $translated == "price":
            $translated = "Precio";
            break;
        case $translated == "Actions":
            $translated = "Acciones";
            break;
        case $translated == "Payment method":
            $translated = "Métodos de pago";
            break;
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Si se fija, en mi Snippet primero hago un `IF` (que lo pude haber metido todo en un case pero lo tengo así porque para mi es lo mejor) sobre una frase completa. Luego hago un `CASE` para una serie de palabras, puede decirle que ese código funciona 100% porque día a día, segundo a segundo se muestra en la web de uno de mis clientes.

Como recomendación le diría que no use el `functions.php` ya que no es recomendable. Si va agregar código lo mínimo que puede hacer es usar **Code Snippet** o en caso contrario hacer un Plugin propio.

PD: Voy a hacer un topic sobre como hacer un Plugin propio de manera sencilla en unos días, ya varias veces he aconsejado lo mismo, creo que es hora de poner ese tema acá :-)

Comment: Efectivamente eso era lo que estaba intentando, pero no hay manera que ese código me funcione, ni ninguno similar, yo también tenía instalado el Code Snippet para evitar tener que tocar el fuction, he visto varias personas que con ese código han resuelto el problema pero a mi no me hace nada, las variables $original, $domain, son nativas de Wordpress o las declara usted?

Comment: Son de WP. Yo solo "relleno" el resto. Super raro que no funcione. Tocará entonces con Loco Translate que por lo general ese si que puede cambiar casi que todos los textos. Aunque si te fijas `$original` podría también ser el texto sin traducir y `$translated` el ya traducido. Pero en mi caso a funcionado así.